# Create private key with CSR

Tags: certificate, keys, csr, private

I have a CSR file (as a text file) and the corresponding P7B certificate. My problem is that I have to create a P12 file on a machine where I do not have created the CSR.

I have created the CSR in Firefox Key Manager. Before, I imported the P7B file into certificate store in msc, then exported a CER-file, imported it in Key Manager and then exported the P12 file. This doesn't work anymore because I have another machine now.

If I try to import the CER file created by msc, Key Manager says that there is no private key.

Is there a possibility to create a private key?

Answer (score 5):

No.  If you could feasibly recreate the private key from a CSR, the whole concept of asymmetric cryptography would be rendered moot.